# clustering opendaylight-boron

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am new to Opendaylight (Boron) clustering using Mininet. I followed the instructions provided through "http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-boron/getting-started-guide/common-features/clustering.html" and I configured three nodes cluster. All three nodes show the full topology of connected switches in the dlux GUI. However, when I try to ping all hosts using the "pingall" command. I am losing most of the packets. and the controller is only showing the part of the hosts in the topology.

h1 -> X X h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
 h2 -> h1 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
 h3 -> h1 h2 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
 h4 -> h1 h2 h3 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
 h5 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
 h6 -> X X X X X X X X X X X X h14 X X 
 h7 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
h8 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
h9 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
h10 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h11 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
h11 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h12 h13 X h15 h16 
h12 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h13 X h15 h16 
h13 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 X h15 h16 
h14 -> X X X X X h6 X X X X X X X X X 
h15 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h16 
h16 -> h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 X h7 h8 h9 h10 h11 h12 h13 X h15 
*** Results: 24% dropped (182/240 received)

the topology works fine when testing under a single controller, I tested different topology sizes, and got the same results. I noticed that My akka.conf file is missing the class "dl-cluster-rpc" when compared to the example in the provided link.

I used the addSwitch and addHost functions to create the switches and hosts before starting the topology

```
        sw = self.addSwitch('c{}'.format(i + 1),cls=OVSKernelSwitch, protocols='OpenFlow13')
            host = self.addHost('h{}'.format(count))
```

the following is how I tried to add multiple controllers in my mininet:

```
    topo = FatTreeTopo()
    net = Mininet(topo=topo, controller=None, link=TCLink)
    cnt1 = net.addController( 'cnt1',controller=RemoteController,ip='159.203.64.13')
    cnt2 = net.addController( 'cnt2',controller=RemoteController,ip='159.203.10.11')
    cnt3 = net.addController( 'cnt3',controller=RemoteController,ip='159.203.18.68')

    info('*** Starting network\n')
    cnt1.start()
    cnt2.start()
    cnt3.start()
    switches = net.switches
    for sname in switches:
        sname.start([cnt1,cnt2,cnt3]
   net.start()
```

I checked all switches being connected to the three controllers using the OVS-VSCTL command:

Bridge "e16"
        Controller "tcp:159.203.103.171:6653"  
            is_connected: true 
        Controller "tcp:159.203.118.68:6653" 
            is_connected: true 
        Controller "tcp:159.203.64.133:6653" 
            is_connected: true

Moreover, the following shows the openflow table for a switch and I see rules for forwarding packet to all three controllers.

**OFPST_FLOW reply (OF1.3) (xid=0x2):
 cookie=0x2b00000000000013, duration=511.822s, table=0, n_packets=206, n_bytes=17510, priority=100,dl_type=0x88cc actions=CONTROLLER:65535
 cookie=0x2b0000000000001a, duration=506.785s, table=0, n_packets=3106, n_bytes=462409, priority=2,in_port=2 actions=output:4,output:3
 cookie=0x2b0000000000001b, duration=506.785s, table=0, n_packets=69, n_bytes=4354, priority=2,in_port=4 actions=output:2,output:3,CONTROLLER:65535
 cookie=0x2b0000000000001c, duration=506.757s, table=0, n_packets=81, n_bytes=4970, priority=2,in_port=3 actions=output:2,output:4,CONTROLLER:65535
 cookie=0x2b00000000000013, duration=511.822s, table=0, n_packets=129, n_bytes=22447, priority=0 actions=drop**

thanks a lot and best wishes

Answer (score 0):

there might be multiple cause for the issue

1) Check the karaf logs

2) Check the entity ownership details

3) Check the datastore shard status

4) Is there any connection flap between controllers, controller and switches

5) check for the flows or entries in operational and config DS.

This should give you fair idea on what is the issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.

Comment: Thanks @EliasMP.. But i do not have enough reputations to comment and I thought since these lines will take you to solution why not give a try. I hope it helps all who are facing same issue,